# Can not find the "variables.tcl" file in Varnish Security

Tags: varnish

Varnish Security main.vcl contains

```
# clear all internal variables
include "/etc/varnish/security/build/variables.vcl";
```

and

```
# fallthrough: clear all internal variables on security.vcl_recv exit
include "/etc/varnish/security/build/variables.vcl";
```

but `/etc/varnish/security/build/variables.vcl` is not included into the git. 
I commented it out, and it is working fine but where can I get that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Makefile](https://github.com/comotion/security.vcl/blob/master/vcl/Makefile) has a target to build the variables file. Run "make all" to generate the file.